# Rename field in relation added to existing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model, migration

I want to add relation that user can belongs_to teacher. Teachers are stored in Admins table. Typically it will be nobody (nil), but for active students, I would add a specific person who is their teacher at the moment.

Normally I think could do run such migration:

```
class AddTeacherToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :users, :admin, index: true
  end
end
```

Then in models, I could add like that:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :admin
 ...

class Admin < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
...
```

But I want to have on my user field `teacher_id`, not `admin_id` is this possible? can I rename a field in migration or inside my model? 
Rails version:  4.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Rails 4.2+ you can set foreign keys in the db:

In your migration do:

```
add_reference :users, :teacher, index: true
add_foreign_key :users, :admins, column: :teacher_id
```

While in your User model do:

```
belongs_to :teacher, class_name: "Admin"
```

Comment: this is exactly what I needed :)

Comment: but also for 
```class Admin < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users, foreign_key: teacher_id```